# Count table difference between two tables by a complex key in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I've two tables in Hive, an external (X) and a managed (M) in Hive.
Both tables have the same columns with complex keys (key_col_a, key_col_b).

How could I count by complex columns, that how many of the records of the first table are in the another table and how many record aren't?

I want to calculate, that how many records should be updated (those which have the same complex key in the another table) and how many should be inserted (those which have totally new keys, unseen before) by using the complex key columns?

This is not working for me:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table_x tx
    LEFT JOIN table_m tm ON 
        tx.key_col_a = tm.key_col_a AND tx.key_col_b = tm.key_col_b
WHERE tm.key_col_a IS NULL OR tm.key_col_b IS NULL;
```

Can someone explain what is the problem with that and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering the table that is being `left join`ed, with a `where`. The result is equivalent to an inner join which is why there are no results. Change the query to

```
SELECT count(case when tm.key_col_a IS NULL OR tm.key_col_b IS NULL then 1 end) as non_matches,
count(tm.key_col_a) as a_matches,
count(tm.key_col_b) as b_matches,
count(case when tm.key_col_a is not null and tm.key_col_b is not null then 1 end) as a_and_b_matches
FROM table_x tx
LEFT JOIN table_m tm ON tx.key_col_a = tm.key_col_a AND tx.key_col_b = tm.key_col_b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()` with `case` statement:

```
SELECT count(case when tm.key_col_a is null     then 1 end) new_rows_cnt,
       count(tm.key_col_a)                                  updated_rows_cnt --counts not null
  FROM table_x tx
       LEFT JOIN table_m tm ON 
                 tx.key_col_a = tm.key_col_a AND tx.key_col_b = tm.key_col_b
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    ,id_a
    ,id_b
FROM tm
WHERE tm.id_a NOT IN (
        SELECT id_a
        FROM tx
        )
    OR tm.id_b NOT IN (
        SELECT id_b
        FROM tx
        )
```

that will give you the number of missing occurrences from tm on tx.